# WSLG on Windows Insider Preview build - Unable to load gui apps

Tags: windows-subsystem-for-linux, wsl-2

Getting can not open display error in wslg on windows Insider build.

Comment: had the same issue, can't get it to work. Did you resolve it in the end?

Answer (score 0):

If you are installing Ubuntu or other distro from Windows Store then they comes with wsl version 1.  wslg is only compatible with WSL 2.

you can list the distros using :

> wsl --list -v

then choose distro you want to use and fire below command:

> wsl --set-version your_distro_name_with_version_goes_here 2

for example:

> wsl --set-version Ubuntu-20.04 2

after that restart wsl using

> wsl --shutdown

Check screen shots for refeence.

Source : https://github.com/microsoft/wslg

[image: commands]

[image: wsl update]

[image: Vola!]

[image: vola it works]